# Documentation for CardView and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying out these new [UIs](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html) from Android L, did not have much issue in implementing the static views but I could not find the relevant documentations for these two views, such as how to call methods to add or remove items from RecyclerView(using `RecyclerView.Adapter` or `LinearLayoutManager`), how to configure behaviours for CardView.

I assume the documentation should be [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/package-summary.html) at the reference page for Android API 20 but I could not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone.

Now CardView and RecyclerView are documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/package-summary.html), after official release of Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

At the present time, `RecyclerView` and `CardView` are part of the "L" Developer Preview, whose documentation is not integrated into the main JavaDocs.

That being said, the documentation is just JavaDocs, and so you will also need to use your favorite search engine to turn up the blog posts and the like that try to fill in the documentation gaps.

Comment: thanks for the download link, I believe the documentations that I needed are there but the hyperlinks are broken due to naming issues. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

What CommonsWare said, with the addition of a popular blog post going into the concepts, along with code examples:

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/

Comment: thanks. I pretty much looked most of the popular blog posts but none of them talked how to really implement the key features associated with these UIs(add or remove items dynamically, or interact with the cardview programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

http://pbz.kt.agh.edu.pl/~krusek/l-developer-preview/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

It's obviously not the official one (Google had one online a few days ago, but they removed it for some reason), but this is pretty accurate. The links there aren't broken, and it's pretty reliable.

Can't seem to find a CardView API document anywhere.